# Videos in facebook embed feed is not displaying in Chrome App

Tags: html, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

EDIT : Actually the issue is this one : Native Videos in embed feed are not supported if user is not logged in. (And so in a webview chrome app, it is not logged in) Bug reported to Facebook here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/353742028342246/ and maybe it is "by design"

---

Old question :

I want to show a Facebook page feed in a Chrome App, it works very well except native videos are not visible.

To reproduce, take the hello world app: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/hello-world

Add `permissions:["webview"]` in manifest.json

Add this after `<h1>Hello, World!</h1>` :

```
<webview src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fyoutube%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></webview>
```

(use this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin and replace 'iframe' with 'webview')

Chrome -> Load Unpacked Extension -> You will see the feed but without the native videos :

[image]

If you open index.html with your browser (and use `<iframe>`) it will show the video...

[image]

If I use `<webview src="https://www.mydomain.fr/company">`, with the correct `<iframe>` in it, same problem : works except native video.

PS : Youtube Videos are working, you can try with the Youtube page:

```
<webview src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fyoutube%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></webview>
```

[image]

Comment: do you have any plugin extension for chrome app??If so what are they??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the bug to Facebook and maybe it is "by design"

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/353742028342246/

waiting for a response by the "team" though.

Comment: so they fixed this bug

Answer (score -1):

First copy the URL of the facebook video you want.

Then go on this page: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player#configurator

Paste the URL where it says "URL of the video", then click Get Code which is located at the bottom.

You can copy the url that is placed in href tags (which is on step 3) and paste it into your editor.